# loop on r studio with a varlist

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am working on a panel database with firms and years. I am interpolating the values to fill the NA, if there are enough observations to interpolate (`um(!is.na(var))>1` needs at least two observations) and keeping the previous values if the variable has not enough values to interpolate (`ifelse(sum(!is.na(var))>1, na_interpolation(var),var)`), in order to not lose values.

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.frame(Output_manufacturing = runif(6),
                   Output_agriculture   = runif(6),
                   ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                   Date=c(1991,20000,1991,2000,1991,2000))

vars <- ls(data, pattern="Output_*")

for (var in vars) {
    data<- data %>%
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      mutate(!!sym(paste0(var, "_interpolated")) := ifelse(sum(!is.na(var))>1, na_interpolation(var),var)) 
  } 
I get the error "Error in for (var in vars) { : invalid for() loop sequence"
```

Comment: I think your code might be wrong, there is no object data_interp

Comment: it was still data. I missed a line of code data_interp <- data

Comment: now there is no ID column

Comment: Where is `na_interpolation` defined?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a `for` loop. I'll use `mtcars` to demonstrate, and a naive assumption of `na_interpolation`'s functionality (which is really tangential to my point):

```r
library(dplyr)
mt <- select(mtcars, cyl, disp, hp, drat) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  ungroup()
mt$disp[c(1,7:8)] <- mt$hp[c(2:3)] <- NA
mt
# # A tibble: 9 x 4
#     cyl  disp    hp  drat
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4   NA     93  3.85
# 2     4  147.    NA  3.69
# 3     4  141.    NA  3.92
# 4     6  160    110  3.9 
# 5     6  160    110  3.9 
# 6     6  258    110  3.08
# 7     8   NA    175  3.15
# 8     8   NA    245  3.21
# 9     8  276.   180  3.07

na_interpolation <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
```

And now the real work:

```r
vars <- c("disp", "hp")
mt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate_at(vars, list(
    interpolated = ~ if (sum(is.na(.)) > 1) na_interpolation(.) else .
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 6
#     cyl  disp    hp  drat disp_interpolated hp_interpolated
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1     4   NA     93  3.85               NA               93
# 2     4  147.    NA  3.69              147.              93
# 3     4  141.    NA  3.92              141.              93
# 4     6  160    110  3.9               160              110
# 5     6  160    110  3.9               160              110
# 6     6  258    110  3.08              258              110
# 7     8   NA    175  3.15              276.             175
# 8     8   NA    245  3.21              276.             245
# 9     8  276.   180  3.07              276.             180
```

---

Side points: `ifelse` with a summary statistic is not the correct tool, for several reasons:

1. `base::ifelse` *can be bad*: it drops class (`ifelse(TRUE,Sys.time(),Sys.time())`) and it does no enforcement on return value type (`ifelse(TRUE,1L,"2")`); both motivated writing `dplyr::if_else` (and `data.table::fifelse`);
2. *Declarative*: if you are confident that your conditional will always be length 1, then declare that by using `if`/`else`; if you see warnings about `the condition has length > 1`, then your assumptions are not true, which means some other assumption about the state of things might not be true; (perhaps not going to happen here, but it's a good defensive programming practice).

This suggests that your code (sans `for` loop) might be:

```r
vars <- grep("^Output_", names(data), value = TRUE)
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars, list(
    interpolated = ~ if (sum(is.na(.)) > 1) na_interpolation(.) else .
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Output_manufacturing Output_agriculture    ID  Date Output_manufacturing_interpolated Output_agriculture_interpolated
#                  <dbl>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                             <dbl>                           <dbl>
# 1                0.266             0.945      1  1991                             0.266                          0.945 
# 2                0.372             0.661      1 20000                             0.372                          0.661 
# 3                0.573             0.629      2  1991                             0.573                          0.629 
# 4                0.908             0.0618     2  2000                             0.908                          0.0618
# 5                0.202             0.206      3  1991                             0.202                          0.206 
# 6                0.898             0.177      3  2000                             0.898                          0.177
```

(It's not clear from this if `na_interpolation` is going to do the right thing, since you have no more than 2 rows per `ID`, and none of your data is `NA`, but I don't think that that matters. The code should still work.)

---

**Updated** to reflect that `mutate_at` is *superseded* in lieu of `mutate(across(...), ...)`.

```r
data %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(vars, list(
    interpolated = ~ if (sum(is.na(.)) > 1) na_interpolate(.) else . 
  ))) %>%
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Output_manufacturing Output_agriculture    ID  Date Output_manufacturing_interpolated Output_agriculture_interpolated
#                  <dbl>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>                             <dbl>                           <dbl>
# 1                0.266             0.945      1  1991                             0.266                          0.945 
# 2                0.372             0.661      1 20000                             0.372                          0.661 
# 3                0.573             0.629      2  1991                             0.573                          0.629 
# 4                0.908             0.0618     2  2000                             0.908                          0.0618
# 5                0.202             0.206      3  1991                             0.202                          0.206 
# 6                0.898             0.177      3  2000                             0.898                          0.177
```